# Run sql file without print its content POSTGRES

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unix

How do I run a .sql file without print its content to the screen
I am running a .sql file using this command

```
psql -h localhost -U usrcashlink -d db_cashlink -a -f /home/cashlink/jenkins_node/cashlink_teste/cashlink_testes/src/test/resources/br/com/softbox/cashlink/massadados/massa_antes.sql
```

However it is printing(logging) the whole file content to the screen.
How do I execute this .sql file without printint its content.

Comment: Please check the answer and in case I missed something do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip at least the option `-a` from your call, thus instead of:

```
psql -h localhost -U usrcashlink -d db_cashlink -a -f /path/to/file.sql
```

try:

```
psql -h localhost -U usrcashlink -d db_cashlink -f /path/to/file.sql
```

You can always ask `psql` on what the arguments mean and what is available. On my system:

```
$ psql --help
psql is the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Usage:
  psql [OPTION]... [DBNAME [USERNAME]]

General options:
  -c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database name to connect to (default: "sthagen")
  -f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit
  -l, --list               list available databases, then exit
  -v, --set=, --variable=NAME=VALUE
                           set psql variable NAME to VALUE
                           (e.g., -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1)
  -V, --version            output version information, then exit
  -X, --no-psqlrc          do not read startup file (~/.psqlrc)
  -1 ("one"), --single-transaction
                           execute as a single transaction (if non-interactive)
  -?, --help[=options]     show this help, then exit
      --help=commands      list backslash commands, then exit
      --help=variables     list special variables, then exit

Input and output options:
  -a, --echo-all           echo all input from script
  -b, --echo-errors        echo failed commands
  -e, --echo-queries       echo commands sent to server
  -E, --echo-hidden        display queries that internal commands generate
  -L, --log-file=FILENAME  send session log to file
  -n, --no-readline        disable enhanced command line editing (readline)
  -o, --output=FILENAME    send query results to file (or |pipe)
  -q, --quiet              run quietly (no messages, only query output)
  -s, --single-step        single-step mode (confirm each query)
  -S, --single-line        single-line mode (end of line terminates SQL command)

Output format options:
  -A, --no-align           unaligned table output mode
  -F, --field-separator=STRING
                           field separator for unaligned output (default: "|")
  -H, --html               HTML table output mode
  -P, --pset=VAR[=ARG]     set printing option VAR to ARG (see \pset command)
  -R, --record-separator=STRING
                           record separator for unaligned output (default: newline)
  -t, --tuples-only        print rows only
  -T, --table-attr=TEXT    set HTML table tag attributes (e.g., width, border)
  -x, --expanded           turn on expanded table output
  -z, --field-separator-zero
                           set field separator for unaligned output to zero byte
  -0, --record-separator-zero
                           set record separator for unaligned output to zero byte

Connection options:
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "local socket")
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port (default: "5432")
  -U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "sthagen")
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)

For more information, type "\?" (for internal commands) or "\help" (for SQL
commands) from within psql, or consult the psql section in the PostgreSQL
documentation.

Report bugs to <pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org>.
```

Another option is always on the shell level to redirect standard out and standard error into files or to `/dev/null` to not have it at all ... like so:

```
psql -h localhost -U usrcashlink -d db_cashlink -f /path/to/file.sql 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
```